# How to use RFT Object Maps in SVN directory?

Tags: automated-testing, rft

I'm experiencing a problem with RFT using SVN as our automation version control.

A lot of our scripts in RFT use the same Object Map.

When 2 users map objects and commit, we cannot merge data, because the Object Map is an XML file with each object written in a unique row.

As you can see, the xml ObjectMap is an infinity single row. when we try to merge data, we do not know where is the differences. i tried to format the file manually, but when RFT write changes in XML, it returns to a single row.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show with an example showing not allowing to merge?